# What is the default size for `driver.manage().window().maximize()` for PhantomJs and HtmlUnit when using selenium-webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, htmlunit, maximize-window

Headless mode is meant to be used on computers without screens, so how does PhantomJS and HtmlUnit figure out the maximized size ?

Answer (score 1):

For HtmlUnit the (default) values are in WebClientOptions

```
private int screenWidth_ = 1024;
private int screenHeight_ = 768;
```

You can change this to any value you like:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
webClient.getOptions().setScreenWidth(640);
webClient.getOptions().setScreenHeight(480);
```